# Table layout broken because of textarea, IE issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-table, textarea

Cannot figure out how one thing is related to another, but see this: http://tinypic.com/r/vecj87/5

Live html here: http://www.papilion.ee/hange_latest/hange_detailvaade.html

Scroll down to the heading "Parimad pakkumised" (or use Ctrl+F).
There's a table.
Click on the link "Vestlus 5" (5 on red) that will open the hidden div with content.

In IE10 and older when this hidden div is opened, the content in the first 'tr' of the table is pushed to right for some reason. I cannot figure out why.
But it seem to be related to textarea inside of hidden div. Making textarea shorter kind of fixes the problem, but I want to keep the textarea long.

See Firefox/Chrome for reference.
Haven't tested on Mac.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with this rule:

```
.infoWrap .answer.action .answer_content textarea.long { width:100%;min-height:64px;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
```